# why do I get this output, but don't use the String

Tags: java, output, tostring

```
public class Card {
    private Rank rank;
    private Suit suit;

    public Card(Rank r, Suit s) {
        this.suit = s;
        this.rank = r;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return rank + " of " + suit;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Card test = new Card(Rank.A, Suit.Clubs);

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

So in my output I have printed A of Clubs. But nowhere am I using toString() I am only defining a new Card from my constructor. So can someone explain to my why I get this output?

Comment: By printing the variable `test`, it calls the `toString()` method that you have overrided

Comment: What if I have myString(), why doesn't call that?

Comment: I would suggest reading the answers below. `toString()` is a function built into Objects, where as `myString()` would be something you just made. It would only call if you wrote `System.out.println(test.myString());` Check out the Java Docs [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the Javadoc and source for PrintWriter.println(Object) you see

```
/**
 * Prints an Object and then terminates the line.  This method calls
 * at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value,
 * then behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>Object</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (lock) {
        print(s);
        println();
    }
}
```

In turn, String.valueOf(Object) does

```
/**
 * Returns the string representation of the {@code Object} argument.
 *
 * @param   obj   an {@code Object}.
 * @return  if the argument is {@code null}, then a string equal to
 *          {@code "null"}; otherwise, the value of
 *          {@code obj.toString()} is returned.
 * @see     java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So you can see that the `toString()` is called for you.

As this is in the documentation, you can assume this won't change in the future or in another implementation. i.e. the code might change but the documented functionality will always be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(test);
```

`toString()` will be called here on `test` to print the output.

Answer (score 1):

When you print out an object, as you do in the last line, it uses to whatever is in the toString() method, if anything.